# modify files in WEB-INF folder - tomcat as hot deployment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, hotdeploy

I have a application deployed in Tomcat7 server which deals with multiple database connections.

These database details are retrieved from 'database.properties' and it is referred in hibernate.xml file in WEB-INF folder. These database details are to be changed dynamically and the hibernate xml is also to be updated.

As for now, if I want to update the database details I need to modify the changes in the 2 files mentioned above and the war file needs to be deployed again.

I tried changing the files in tomcat without restarting. I verified that the '*reloadable*' property in tomcat server.xml file is set to **true**. But still the changes are not reflected in the app without restarting the server.

Please let me know if any configurations to be done for modifying these files without restarting the tomcat server.....

-- 
Suriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [**WatchedResource**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Nested_Components) tag. You need to add your files there.

> WatchedResource - The auto deployer will monitor the specified static resource of the web application for updates, and will reload the web application if it is updated. The content of this element must be a string.

Look at the configuration in context.xml file

```
<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
```

Add more files, which you want to monitor the changes to redeploy.